# Total object deletion in python

Tags: python, class, global

Is there any way to ensure that when an object is deleted, it is deleted fully from wherever it is?

For example, if you did something like:

```
A = NewObject()
B = NewObject()
C = NewObject()

List1 = [A,B,C]
List2 = [1,2,3,C]

del A
del List2[3]
```

and have the objects deleted wherever they are, meaning that `List1` would only contain B and that `List2` would only contain 1,2,3.

Is there any way that behavior similar to this could be achieved?

Comment: I have accepted all answers on all of my questions that have received answers that answer the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [weak references](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) in some cases. If you don't care if `C` remains alive in `List2`, you can wrap it in a weakref, and when the reference to `C` expires from List1, the garbage collector will collect any memory associated with it.

Python uses reference counting to decide whether or not an object should be collected, so as long as a reference is held somewhere, you can not fully delete that object. However, if a weakref wraps an object, that reference is not counted. So when the count drops to 0, it'll be collected at the GC convenience.

Make sure to fully read the documentation though, since there are quite a few caveats associated with weakrefs. Especially the types of objects that are eligible to be used within a weakref.

Edit:

An example -

```
>>> class List(list):
...     pass
... 
>>> weaklist = List()
>>> weaklist.append('a')
>>> weaklist.append('b')
>>> stronglist = [ ['c','d','e'] ]
>>> weaklist
['a', 'b']
>>> stronglist
[['c', 'd', 'e']]
>>> import weakref
>>> stronglist.append(weakref.ref(weaklist))
>>> stronglist
[['c', 'd', 'e'], <weakref at 0x10046e578; to 'List' at 0x100455f70>]
>>> stronglist[1]()
['a', 'b']
>>> del weaklist
>>> stronglist
[['c', 'd', 'e'], <weakref at 0x10046e578; dead>]
>>> stronglist[1]()
>>>
```

I highly advise reading the entire documentation on weakrefs. It sounds like you want to build up a node structure, but be able to reference that node structure from a Manager. You would create your nodes as regular objects, but place weakrefs to those objects within the Manager. In that way, when a node is removed, the reference within the Manager simply dies.

A candidate for this would be the `WeakValueDictionary` defined within the weakref module.

Comment: This looks like it is going the right direction but i cant get it to work as it is explained in the docs i.e. http://pastebin.com/BsximMga is there any certainty as to when the garbage collector will be run

Comment: @Hugo, see my edit. You actually need to create a weakref wrapper around what you want to expire.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You're [deleting a name](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#del), not the actual object.  There is no reason or mechanism to cause an object to be destroyed (and other names deleted) when only a single name is deleted.

Comment: I was aware it only deleted the name thats why i was asking if there was any way the functionality could be achieved

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this, it won't work anyways. Structure your program in a way that objects get automatically deleted when they are not needed anymore.

Maybe you want to free some external resources that your object uses. Don't use object deletion for that (`__del__` is not a deconstructor!) - use the context manager protocol (aka the `with` statement) instead. I can't really think of any other reason to try this ...

Comment: The reason i am trying to do this is that in the program i am working on i have a node system that consists of an overall manager class, a node class and a link class, i am having problems where trying to delete a link will still leave references to it in places such as the manager and the point objects